# Delete cells in customized groups instead of entire rows or columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which deletes cells by the entire column. Initally i thought it would be of good use, later i realised that if i do so, the useful data on that same column would get deleted too . Hence i need a code which allows me to delete any range of cells be it rows or columns at my own convenience

```
Sub TestDatabase()

Dim rng As range, rngError As range, delRange As range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)

On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub Else rng.delete

For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'runs through all worksheets

  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k)

  With wks

    For i = 1 To 7 '<~~ Loop trough columns A to G

        '~~> Check if that column has any errors
        On Error Resume Next

        Set rngError = .Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
            For j = 1 To 100 '<~~ Loop Through rows 1 to 100
                If .Cells(j, i).Text = "#REF!" Then
                    '~~> Store The range to be deleted
                    If delRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set delRange = .Columns(i)
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Columns(i))
                    End If
                End If
             Next j
         End If

     Next i

  End With

Next k

'~~> Delete the range in one go
If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.delete

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like your code deletes the values in a given range of cells (on a single worksheet) then checks all the worksheets in the workbook (including the sheet with the deleted range) for any `#REF!` errors. If any errors are found, the values/formulas in the error cells are deleted also. Is this correct and your intention?

Comment: Yup thats right except the part where you mentioned it will check all ref errors in the workbook. it actually loops through the sheets to delete ranges and ref errors at the same time instead of one single sheet. @PeterT

Comment: You're asking for the capability to "delete any range of cells be it rows or columns at my own convenience". Does your VBA code above meet your needs? If not, why not? I'm honestly not seeing the connection between your stated goal and the code you've posted.

Comment: it does not allow me to delete rows only columns. that is my problem . i want it to be able to delete any rows or columns not just column only or row only @PeterT

Comment: OK, can you post any picture for your input and output sample. So, we can think more.

Comment: Rather than looping through each column, why not search the active region for errors, and then loop through the range and delete the column and row of the resulting cells?

Comment: because there is a separate deletion function associated with it. @aebailey. If I were to search, the ref errors would seem visible , which is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in order to achieve your needs, you simply need to remove the `.Columns()` method. This in turn brings the new problem of - when you delete a cell, which way should Excel shift the remaining cells?

You could try something like this:

```
If .Cells(j, i).Text = "#REF!" Then
    '~~> Store The range to be deleted
    If delRange Is Nothing Then
        Set delRange = .Cells(j, i)
        '// Exit For <~~ This stops your code adding any more cells to delRange
    Else
        Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(j, i))
    End If
End If
```

and then when you delete:

```
'// Could use xlUp, xlDown, xlToRight or xlToLeft
delRange.delete shift:=xlUp
```

It is worth noting that because `delRange` now points to a group of cells, you can delete:

- The cells only, using the method above.
- The rows belonging to these cells using `delRange.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp`
- Or the columns belonging to these cells, using `delRange.EntireColumn.Delete shift:=xlToLeft`

Comment: It works just fine but only a row only or column only . Any ways to delete multiple rows or columns? for example range D1 to E13. Because when i deleted that range, it gave me ref errors again:/

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete additional rows or columns that aren't in `delRange` ?

Comment: within the range! I just realised that the programme does not delete columns and gives me lot of reference errors.

Comment: Right, I think I know what you problem is - when you run this code does it only remove **one** row or column instead of removing all of them within the range?

Comment: it removes  row successfully but it does not remove the column or any group of cells., instead it gives refernce errors for that entire column or group i chose to delete

Comment: See my edit above, comment out the `Exit For` as this is just jumping to the next worksheet as soon as it finds an error cell rather than searching through the rest of the cells. Because of this, there will only ever be one cell in `delRange` and therefore only 1 row will ever be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Though I'm still unclear about your ultimate purpose, deleting any size or shape range is fairly straightforward. As in clearing (or deleting) all your `#REF!` errors.

I do suggest you pick up [Peter Thornton's `GetInputRange` function](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/SelectARange.asp), which can solve any potential problems you may have using the `InputBox` to get a Range from your user.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim targetArea As Range
    Dim success As Boolean

    '--- clears only the contents from the currently selected area
    Set targetArea = Application.Selection
    targetArea.ClearContents
    '--- optionally delete the area, but this shifts all the other data into the area
    'targetArea.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    ClearAllRefErrors

    '--- asks for the area to be cleared
    '    uses Peter Thornton's GetInputRange method (http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/SelectARange.asp)
    success = GetInputRange(targetArea, "Enter the range to delete:", "Delete Range", _
                           Application.Selection.Address)
    If success Then
        targetArea.ClearContents
        '--- optionally delete the area, but this shifts all the other data into the area
        'targetArea.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        ClearAllRefErrors
    End If
End Sub

Sub ClearAllRefErrors()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rangeInUse As Range
    Dim rangeCell As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set rangeInUse = Application.ActiveSheet.usedRange
        For Each rangeCell In rangeInUse
            If rangeCell = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
                rangeCell.ClearContents
                '--- optionally delete the cell, but this shifts all the other data
                'rangeCell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            End If
        Next rangeCell
    Next ws
End Sub
```